# Grant Issue In ubuntu

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, stored-procedures, sql-grant

I am Using Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) 64-bit Since i am new to Ubuntu i am having issue with grant
I'm using following cmd to grant in Ubuntu example

> Sudo mysql -u root -p
> create user username identified by 'pass'
>
> grant all privilege on Db.* to username

if check grants using

> show grants for username

| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD |

now if i login as user-name it will not ask for password it will directly login without password if i enter password for user it gives me error message:

> sudo mysql -u username -p

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user user-name (using password: YES)

and after login if i give

> show databases (it will not show any databases which is granted)

please guide me with an  example

And also i would like to know tat if stored procedure is created in root how to get access
for other user even tho if i give grant for the particular stored procedure to other user
is there some thing to do with definer

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to run `sudo` to just connect to MySQL as root.

Create a database:

```
$ mysqladmin create mydatabase -uroot -p
```

Connect as root or another user who can grant permissions

```
$ mysql -D mydatabase -uroot -p
```

Allow `foouser` to connect from this very same machine

```
mysql> grant all privileges on mydatabase.* to 'foouser'@'localhost' identified by 'pass';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> quit
Bye
```

Connect as your new user:

```
$ mysql -D mydatabase -u foouser -p
Enter password: pass
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 129
Server version: 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: Dear Denis Fuenzalida,                                         Thanks for replying                                                          As you guided I have followed the procedure for granting the user but problem is tat when I try to acess the user it showing me the error v@v:~$ mysql -D testing -u du -p                                      
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'du'@'localhost' (using password:YES)                                                        Is there any thing to be done in my.conf file to get access

Comment: The only comment I have done on /etc/mysql/my.cnf is to comment the following line: 
# bind-address  = 127.0.0.1